# Balancing page which has few elements

Tags: usability, interaction-design, layout

How i got few pages, where i have a search page like below, It display features of web store and a search box to search. The page looks pretty empty and a lot of space is getting wasted, in other words the page look dull for a search page, as there is a another page, which have a drop down menu and that is it. While search page is the main item for a website to retain customer, How can i make it more interactive?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMy86Q.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFidn.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second wireframe looks filled and balanced. For the first wireframe - since the selected option in combo-box is *'Select Your Favorite Color'* think of **showing some colors below the dropdown; i.e Frequently used colors / Recently used colors**.

Get inspired by Chrome's landing page:

[image]

Comment: The first one mock up, text might be different it can be type of garments. i.e. Polos, bags, Tees etc, it is not limited to just colours.

Comment: @Nofel Then use the block/cards to display popular categories that will be beneficial to business.